# slow start after removing a hard disk

Tags: startup

I use Ubuntu 18.04.03, and the start was always very fast. But since I removed one of my hard disks, the procces of start takes a long time.
I think somewhere there is a reference to de missing disk and the system is trying to find it until a timeout period.
Where should I look for that reference to the removed disk?
Or is something else?
thanks

@heynnema

sudo blkid

> /dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
>
> /dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
>
> /dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
>
> /dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
>
> /dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
>
> /dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
>
> /dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
>
> /dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
>
> /dev/sda1: LABEL="Documentos" UUID="c7ecde30-afc1-4320-a4f7-250339941376" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="00000001-01"
>
> /dev/sdb1: LABEL="Xubuntu" UUID="5c2cdc58-c196-487f-91c7-b2e36ef55a4e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="5919caf1-01"
>
> /dev/sdb2: UUID="6e0d21bf-e194-4472-a643-abc5283dde47" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="5919caf1-02"
>
> /dev/sdc1: LABEL="Win7Sis" UUID="EE525BDC525BA85B" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="fb0ffb0f-01"
>
> /dev/sdc5: LABEL="Win7Datos" UUID="F8966C6B966C2BF6" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="fb0ffb0f-05"

cat /etc/fstab

> # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
>
> #
>
> # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
>
> # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
>
> # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
>
> #
>
> # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
>
> # / was on /dev/sdc1 during installation
>
> UUID=5c2cdc58-c196-487f-91c7-b2e36ef55a4e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
>
> # /home was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
>
> UUID=c7ecde30-afc1-4320-a4f7-250339941376 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
>
> # swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
>
> UUID=af9cbf4b-7a29-422e-b24a-e620301b8369 none            swap    sw              0       0
>
> # swap was on /dev/sdc2 during installation
>
> UUID=6e0d21bf-e194-4472-a643-abc5283dde47 none            swap    sw              0       0

I understand that at instalation time, the disks and partitions were named different than now

Comment: As I don't see anything obvious in the added output. Could you add the output of `systemd-analyze blame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `terminal`...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` # edit fstab file

change:

```
UUID=af9cbf4b-7a29-422e-b24a-e620301b8369 none swap sw 0 0
```

to:

```
#UUID=af9cbf4b-7a29-422e-b24a-e620301b8369 none swap sw 0 0
```

save the file and quit gedit.

Comment: Thanks. It works.

Now I see that the disk with UUID=af9cbf4b-7a29-422e-b24a-e620301b8369 is not present in my system, but I didn't know where to look for