# Can a swapfile slow down booting in Linux?

Tags: boot, swap

Since some time I have problems that my Linux Ubuntu 18.04 is very slowly booting (sometimes 5-10 minutes).
Strangely, this seems to have started since I edited the Swapfile or/and that I used Gparted. The `top` command and `swapon -s` command show that the Swapfile is working (I reserved 4 GB).

But the following command showed something weird:

```
sudo findmnt --verify --verbose
```

All lines are fine except the following **warning** appears:

```
[W] non-bind mount source /swapfile is a directory or regular file
```

What does that line exactly mean? Does it mean that it could not mount the swapfile? (while actually in the end it is working). So I wondered if something is wrong in my fstab file.

```
cat /etc/fstab
```

The swap line gives the following:

```
/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
```

I heard that problems of finding and mounting the swapfile during boot can slow down the whole process. The swapfile is running from the main disk so I wondered if the above line should be changed in something like this:

```
UUID=xx9999x9-9x99-9xx9-9999-xx9x9xx99xx9/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
```

Where the UUID is the hard disk. I did not use any partitioning.

Systemd-analyze blame gives the following output:

```
systemd-analyze blame | head

     17.041s dev-sda1.device
     11.192s dev-loop9.device
     11.056s dev-loop16.device
     10.964s dev-loop14.device
     10.704s dev-loop6.device
     10.703s dev-loop1.device
     10.703s dev-loop7.device
     10.703s dev-loop2.device
     10.702s dev-loop4.device
     10.687s dev-loop13.device
```

After having used `sudo apt-get purge snapd` this is the following:

```
systemd-analyze blame | head
    7.902s dev-sda1.device
    7.152s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
    5.121s ufw.service
    4.792s systemd-udevd.service
    4.539s docker.service
    4.298s accounts-daemon.service
    4.152s systemd-journal-flush.service
    3.970s apparmor.service
    3.808s avahi-daemon.service
    3.751s bluetooth.service
```

The command `sudo blkid` gives one line (I anonymized the ID). Previously, there were a lot of lines /dev/loopX: TYPE="squashfs"

```
    /dev/sda1: UUID="xx9999x9-9x99-9xx9-9999-xx9x9xx99xx9" TYPE="ext4"   PARTUUID="9999xx999-01"
```

A screenshot of `Disks` parameters:

[SMART Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9OpG.png)

Output of syslog:

```
grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*

[   48.245514] ata6.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[   48.247916] ata6.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[   48.250316] ata6.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[   48.252774] ata6.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
```

Here follows a screenshot of Gparted:

[Gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJRMM.png)

*Another observation*: when I start the computer, the screen stays black 5-10 minutes. Then after long waiting, it gives a title screen with the laptop mark. From there all seems to run smoothly. Just wanted to say this as it may indicate where during the booting something is going wrong. I wondered if the boot loader (Grub) can be broken, since I previously run dual boot on this system and removed Windows 7 recently.

File system table

```
sudo cat /etc/fstab

    # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
    # / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
    UUID=ae2158a5-6f28-4da8-8082-cc6d6bb20ed2 /               ext4       errors=remount-ro 0       1
    /swapfile none            swap    sw              0       0


sudo blkid
    /dev/sda1: UUID="ae2158a5-6f28-4da8-8082-cc6d6bb20ed2" TYPE="ext4"  PARTUUID="630bb523-01"
```

**BIOS version**

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
1.03.05
```

Motherboard infos:

```
TUXEDO Book DC1504
Model: W650SJ
Clevo CO

sudo dmidecode -t 2
# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.8 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
Manufacturer: Notebook                        
Product Name: W65_67SJ                        
Version: Not Applicable                  
Serial Number: Not Applicable                  
Asset Tag: Tag 12345
Features:
    Board is a hosting board
    Board is replaceable
Location In Chassis: Not Applicable
Chassis Handle: 0x0003
Type: Motherboard
Contained Object Handles: 0
```

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

**Grub**

The command `dpkg -l grub* | grep ii` gives the following output:

```
ii  grub-common           2.02-2ubuntu8.18 amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader (common files)

ii  grub-gfxpayload-lists 0.7              amd64        GRUB gfxpayload blacklist

ii  grub-pc               2.02-2ubuntu8.18 amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (PC/BIOS version)

ii  grub-pc-bin           2.02-2ubuntu8.18 amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (PC/BIOS binaries)

ii  grub2-common          2.02-2ubuntu8.18 amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader (common files for version 2)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your /etc/fstab /swapfile line is fine. Don't add UUID. What commands did you use to "started since I edited the Swapfile"? What did you do with `gparted`? All of these details should be in your question. Hit the ESC key during boot, and see where booting stops... that will give a clue as to why it's taking so long to boot.

Comment: What is the output of `systemd-analyze blame | head` in your system? Please [edit] your question and add this info.

Comment: Might be related to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056645/what-are-the-dev-loop-services-that-started-on-boot . It seems to me that snaps (some misconfiguration?) are causing the problem. Paste also the output of `losetup` command to your original question.

Comment: I think the issue can be A) You've misconfigured something B) it's the snaps removing all cut 2+ minutes C) based on my 2 tb luks hdd (~4 ms with fsck) your sda1 is taking a bit long, is it running fsck? What filesystem,partition,free space,fstab parameters do you have on it?

Comment: @kortewegdevries It's probably A.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli: Thank you. I have followed the advice in the link and used `sudo apt-get purge snapd`. That does clearly improve the noted times in `system-analyze blame | head`, but booting remains very slow. Is it possible that an outdated or broken Grub causes these kind of problems?

Comment: Can you [edit] and update your original question, by pasting the new output of `system-analyze blame | head`?

Answer (score 2):

You probably made a mistake when you "edited" the /swapfile.

- *"seems to have started since I edited the Swapfile"*
- *"/swapfile is a directory or regular file"*

The **correct** process for creating/resizing to a 4G /swapfile...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm nnG RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Update #1:**

You have some NCQ errors with your disk.

Native Command Queuing (NCQ) is an extension of the Serial ATA protocol allowing hard disk drives to internally optimize the order in which received read and write commands are executed.

Edit `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` and change the following line to include this extra parameter. Then do `sudo update-grub` to write the changes to disk. Reboot. Monitor hangs, and watch `/var/log/syslog` or `dmesg` for continued error messages.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"
```

If this doesn't help cure the problem, we'll come back and bad block the disk.

**Update #2:**

Since you're still having problems, we'll do this to troubleshoot the slow startup times.

Edit /etc/default/grub.

change this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"
```

to this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="libata.force=noncq"
```

then:

```
sudo update-grub

reboot
```

This will now show a lot of text on the screen during the reboot. When it stalls or pauses, the last item on the screen will give us a clue as to what's wrong. Take a clear picture of that and upload it into your question, and then ping me.

Your SMART data doesn't show any bad block problems. It DOES show lots of read errors, which the NCQ patch MAY have taken care of.

**Update #3:**

**Note**: You should have good backups, just in case of problems.

We'll update your ramdisk, and reinstall GRUB.

---

`ls -al /boot/initrd*` # note the size of these files

`sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)` # recreate the ramdisk file

`ls -al /boot/initrd*` # note if the file sizes have changed

`reboot` # see if it boots any faster now

---

`dpkg -l grub* | grep ii` # show current grub file packages installed

`sudo apt install --reinstall package_name_here` # for each GRUB package listed above

`sudo update-grub` # update GRUB

`reboot` # see if it boots any faster now

**Update #4:**

To check for a newer BIOS, you must create a user account at https://www.tuxedocomputers.com/index.php?module=account

To contact Tuxedo support, call tel:+4982189982992, and email at https://www.tuxedocomputers.com/en/Contact.tuxedo

Comment: Sorry but I don't find this answer to be very relevant to the problem Partoudata is having. The swapfile made is already working: "The top command and swapon -s command show that the Swapfile is working" and isn't contributing to the slow boot time as much as the snaps are.

Comment: @kortewegdevries If you read closer, you'll note *"seems to have started since I edited the Swapfile or/and that I used Gparted"* and *"/swapfile is a directory or regular file"*... so what better place to start, than with the possibility that something was done incorrectly with /swapfile?

Comment: @heynnema: thank you for your help! I followed your advice, unfortunately recreating the swapfile does not change anything. To be fair, I am not really sure when the problems with booting started, it may already have started before re-partitioning. I saw the following post where you answered a question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189592/slow-start-after-removing-a-hard-disk. I noticed there something different in the formatting of fstab. Shouldn't the format be like `UUID=af9cbf4b-7a29-422e-b24a-e620301b8369 none swap sw 0 0` or rather `/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0` ?

Comment: @Partoudata Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/fstab` and show me a screenshot of `gparted`, and tell me what changes you made using `gparted`.

Comment: @Partoudata Also show me `sudo blkid`.

Comment: @Partoudata Also show me screenshot(s) of the `Disks` app scrollable SMART Data window.

Comment: @Partoudata Status please...

Comment: @heynnema: What do you mean with "Disks app scrollable SMART Data window", do you mean a test with Smartmontools package of the harddrive? ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools )

Comment: @Partoudata No. In the `Disks` app, there's a SMART Data window which shows various parameters from the disk. This window is scrollable, although it doesn't look like it with a scroll bar on the right. I need screenshots of all of the parameters. Also, please show me ALL of the requested information, and don't redact any info like UUIDs, or I can't help. Redacting loop info is fine.

Comment: @heynnema: Sorry, can you give an URL to anything about `Disks` app? Tried to Google it but it does not give a clear result.

Comment: @Partoudata Just hit the SUPER key and type `Disks`.

Comment: @Partoudata Thanks for the SMART Data. You have lots of read and seek errors. Show me `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*`.

Comment: @heynnema: the harddisk is a Seagate, they tell measuring read and seek gives always inflated values. What do you think? Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Partoudata No, read/seek errors are important. Was there only 4 items shown from the last `grep` command, or were there more? You have some disk NCQ errors. Also, is yours an older BIOS computer, or a newer UEFI computer? Please tell me how/why your repartitioned with `gparted`. Is this a desktop or laptop computer? Then I can update my answer.

Comment: @Partoudata I also still need to see `cat /etc/fstab` and `sudo blkid` (without redactions). And show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model # of your computer or motherboard. Thanks.

Comment: @Partoudata Please see Update #1 in my answer. Reboot and report back. Remember to flag me with a comment that starts with "@heynnema". Thanks for the other infos. I do need the exact make/model # to see if there's a newer BIOS available. I couldn't find that with the info you've given.

Comment: @heynnema: When I started the machine today it was "surprisingly" faster. No blackscreen, directly the laptop trademark, as it used to be. This was before I made the changes that you propose under #1. I think it may be because of `sudo update-grub` I did. Hope it stays this way. Thank you for your kind help!

Comment: @heynnema: For learning purposes, could you tell how you identified the NCQ errors on the disk?

Comment: If we modify the previous `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*` command, to `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog* -B5 -A5 | more` you'll see `ncq` listed in that output. Have you done Update #1 from my answer?

Comment: @Partoudata Status please...

Comment: @heynnema: For a while booting was fast but it has reverted to the previous state and actually worse, it is now taking one hour to start Ubuntu. I wonder if the hard drive has any problem. When it is finally running everything works smooth, only the mouse freezes now and then (reconnecting it to the USB helps). I have done Update #1 as you asked. As you suggested in your answer to bad block the disk I have run yesterday `sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda1 > badsectors.txt` which gave surprisingly *Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)*. What is the right way to bad block the disk?

Comment: @Partoudata See Update #2 in my answer.

Comment: @heynnema: Thank you! You mentioned "Note: do NOT bad block a SSD". Mine is SSHD. Is there any danger of damaging the disk using `sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` or is it safe?

Comment: @Partoudata I guess that it's probably not a good idea to BB a SSHD. But you don't have any bad blocks that I can tell. I reworked my answer for that. Did you do the NCQ patch? Did you do the first part of Update #2 yet?

Comment: @heynnema: Yes, regarding the NCQ, I have used `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="libata.force=noncq" ` .
The screen messages come only after 30-60 minutes waiting a black screen where nothing seems to happen.
When after this long time the messages appear, it is all pass (green), no failures. It does not stall, at this point booting has no problems. Could the actual problem occur before the booting process?

Comment: @Partoudata I haven't been able to check on your BIOS with the info that you've given. Please tell me the exact make/model # of your computer or motherboard. Next we'll rebuild your ramdisk, and reinstall GRUB. Give me a few minutes to update my answer.

Comment: @heynnema: I have done the steps you indicated under #Update 3 with 2 reboots and it did not improve. I have updated the infos in the question (see **Grub**) and I wondered if grub and grub2 could interfere in some way, or if any of the grub packages seems strange to you. Could you tell me what exact motherboard info you would need?

Comment: @Partoudata I need the make/model # of your computer, or motherboard (if home built). See the tag on the bottom of the computer. For example: Dell Inspiron 54321.

Comment: @Heynnema: I have added it under *Motherboard infos*.

Comment: @Partoudata To determine if there's a newer BIOS available, they want you to log into your Tuxedo account at https://www.tuxedocomputers.com/index.php?module=account

Comment: @Heynnema: thank you for the link! I have made an account but as I am not the original but second-hand user of this laptop I do not have access to the needed BIOS pack. Nor does Tuxedo respond to my requests. Is there an alternative to find the needed BIOS pack?

Comment: @Partoudata Have you tried to phone call them, and/or sent email? Their phone # is tel:+4982189982992, and email at https://www.tuxedocomputers.com/en/Contact.tuxedo

Comment: @heynnema: Finally could reach them by telephone. Their support suggests not replacing the BIOS but rather unplug the harddrive and boot without harddrive. I am bit confused if this is a way to go... what do you think?

Comment: @Partoudata **EVERY** company **suggests** not to upgrade the BIOS... **IF** the machine is operating normally. Yours is not. How can you boot if the hard disk is unplugged? Kind of stupid. I'd call them again and get the BIOS updater.